# Обратиться к элементу списка словарей

Tags: python, dataframe

Имеется набор данных DataFrame. В нем столбец key_skills. В key_skills в каждой строке либо пустой список, либо список словарей в формате:

```
 [{'name': 'PHP'}, {'name': '1С-Битрикс'}, {'name': 'Git'}, {'name': 'MySQL'}, {'name': 'CSS3'}, {'name': 'ООП'}, {'name': 'API'}, {'name': 'HTML5'}]
```

Как считать каждый элемент name? То есть получить значения: PHP, 1С-Битрикс, Git, MySQL и т.д.

Так получаю значения словаря в столбце, но для списка словарей это не работает:

```
df['skills'] = df['key_skills'].map(lambda x: x.get("name", np.nan) if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, соответственно, перебираете этот список и к его элементам применяете эту вашу функцию:

```py
df['skills'] = df['key_skills'].map(lambda y: [x.get("name", np.nan) if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan for x in y])
```

Ну там ещё можно что-то подкрутить, не совсем понятно, что нужно в итоге получить.

|  | key_skills | skills |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [{'name': 'PHP'}, {'name': '1С-Битрикс'}, {'na... | [PHP, 1С-Битрикс, Git, MySQL, CSS3, ООП, API, ... |
| 1 | [] | [] |

Comment: Судя по вашей таблице, получается как раз то, что нужно.
Но в моем коде данная строка выдает ошибку TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конце перед скобкой ещё `if isinstance(x, list)`

Comment: if isinstance(y, list). Спасибо, сработало