# Как обратиться к массиву листов?

Tags: python

Вот мой массив

```
[{'name': 'WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)', 'description': 'Hastra Agency ищет разработчика с опытом работы с связи с ростом отдела SEO-продвижения. Требуемый о...', 'key_skills': ['HTML', 'CSS', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'SE']}, {.....}, {....}]
O']
```

Как я могу обратиться к какому-нибудь элементу?

К примеру, мне надо вытащить из первого элемента листа WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)

Comment: По идее так `[0]['key_skills'][1]`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1409879/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9

Comment: удивительно, но факт. Тут нет ни массива, ни каких-то мифических листов.

Comment: за оскорбление `списка словарей` фразой "массив листов" - минус сразу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала напечатаем вашу коллекцию в более понятном виде через `pprint` (отрезав многоточия всякие в конце, и элементы словаря перемешались, но это не важно):

```py
data = \
[{'description': 'Hastra Agency ищет разработчика с опытом работы с связи с '
                 'ростом отдела SEO-продвижения. Требуемый о...',
  'key_skills': ['HTML', 'CSS', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'SE'],
  'name': 'WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)'}]
```

- `[...]` - это список, перебирать список можно через `for`, а элементы брать через индексацию `[index]`
- `{...}` - это словарь, можно его перебирать через `for` по `.items()`, а элементы брать тоже через ключ `[key]`

Итого, если взять конкретный элемент без перебора:

```py
print(data[0]['name'])
```